# Reconstruct component in runtime and reinject dependencies which were already injected in the same Fragment

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I have a subcomponent(**componentA**) in the android app which has it's own scope.

**componentA** gets constructed based on contents of **ObjectA** which is fetched from some kind of storage.

In Fragments which are connected to the scope of **componentA** I call **componentA.inject(this)** in **onCreate()** method.

The problem is, that now every time application returns from background, if **ObjectA** has expired.

I have to fetch **ObjectA** again and construct **componentA** and some how reinject dependencies provided by **componentA** which has already been injected in onCreate() in the same Fragment.

Dependencies should be also updated for the fragments in backstack when the user returns back to the Fragment.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: `componentA gets constructed based on the contents of ObjectA...` that's probably not a good way to do things. Please have a look at some of the Dagger 2 examples to see the basic patterns you should be following https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture

Comment: David, all the dependencies provided by componentA have a Scope of ObjectA. When ObjectA is invalid, the dependencies become invalid as well. This is the same as for example User's scope.
http://frogermcs.github.io/dependency-injection-with-dagger-2-custom-scopes/
I need a way to recreate ComponentA after loading ObjectA when the app comes from background and then reinject dependencies with the new componentA

Comment: Can you produce `componentA` from a `Provider<ObjectA>` rather than from `ObjectA`?